Characters ��� appears when load turns on
I'm making an automatic watering system with an LCD that shows moisture level from 0 to 100. Whenever the pump turns on the output on the serial monitor turns into ��� and other random characters. This also happens on the LCD. Any advice on how I can fix this?
I've already tried adding delay in the baud and ensuring that its at 9600.
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

const int soilAnalog = A0;
int soilVal;
int outputVal;

const int pump = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Ensure Serial Monitor is set to 9600 baud
  delay(500);
  
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();


  pinMode(pump, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  soilVal = analogRead(soilAnalog);
  Serial.print("Analog Output: ");
  Serial.println(soilVal);
  
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Moisture Level:");

  // Map soilVal to a percentage (0-100)
  outputVal = map(soilVal, 0, 1023, 100, 0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(outputVal);
  lcd.print("   ");

  if (soilVal >= 700) {
    Serial.println("Status: Dry");
    digitalWrite(pump, HIGH);
  } 
  else if (soilVal >= 400 && soilVal < 700) {
    Serial.println("Status: Moist");
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("Status: Wet");
    digitalWrite(pump, LOW);
  }

  Serial.println();
  delay(1500);
}


Do you have the motor powered off of one of the pins on the Arduino?

Show us a schematic of your project

your code doesn't turn the pump anywhere. Is the pump an external element to your system? It could be that it generates noise in the power line. Use a proper voltage regulator to filter the power input to the Arduino. It should filter spikes and other sudden changes in voltage.
